# How to let user resize the "joint.shapes.devs.Atomic" object?

Tags: javascript, jointjs

How to  let use  re-size the `joint.shapes.devs.Atomic` object? I know how to re-size on a button or on some other action. But how to let the user select the boundary and drag it? I have seen it in the Rappid, but how to do that using joint js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely mean the Rappid FreeTransform plugin, which is not part of the joint js library.

The way how to do it in `joint js` is to implement your own widget for resizing, then it will call the `resize` method on a shape. Check `joint.dia.Element` signature where resize is defined.

Comment: Thanks you, I am new to Joint Js , Not sure how to add widget . Please give some pointer ....